# KSQL average value in some x number of messages

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

i have a running instance of kafka-confluent and a topic named  "mqtt-source-1" that reads this structured json messages

```
{
    "device1": {
        "t": "timestamp",
        "id": "deviceid",
        "type": "presence",
        "m": [
            {
                "t": "nowTimestamp()",
                "tz": "now()",
                "k": "device_temperature",
                "v": "double(0, 40)",
                "u": "C"
            },
            {
                "t": "nowTimestamp()",
                "tz": "now()",
                "k": "battery_level",
                "v": "double(3.26, 3.56)",
                "u": "V"
            }
        ]
    },
    "device2": {
        "t": "timestamp",
        "id": "deviceid",
        "type": "presence",
        "m": [
            {
                "t": "nowTimestamp()",
                "tz": "now()",
                "k": "device_temperature",
                "v": "double(0, 40)",
                "u": "C"
            },
            {
                "t": "nowTimestamp()",
                "tz": "now()",
                "k": "battery_level",
                "v": "double(3.26, 3.56)",
                "u": "V"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

It is possible to get average value of v grouped by m->k and deviceid calculated on certain x number of messages?

Answer (score 0):

If not yet done, you need to create a topic that is capable of parsing the incoming messages correctly. This blog posts describes how to handle JSONs and arrays inside a JSON: https://rmoff.net/2020/05/26/working-with-json-nested-arrays-in-ksqldb-example/

Now, if I understand your last sentence correctly, you want to aggregate by {m->k, deviceid}. You can do this with the `CREATE TABLE <<name>> AS SELECT <<your desired columns>> FROM <<input stream that contains the parsed JSONs>>` statement. Use plain SQL syntax to group by {m->k, deviceid} and create a column applying AVG(m->v). This should do it.

Comment: Ok for get avg value,how can i get avg value in a window tumbling query. I tried to do some test but window tumbling add strange character on message key :(

Comment: example query: CREATE TABLE MSG_COUNT_STREAM WITH (value_format='AVRO') AS SELECT 'X',COUNT(*) AS MSG_CT FROM my_stream WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 2 MINUTES) GROUP BY 'X' emit changes;

Comment: @dune98 Could you please describe more precisely what behavior you observe and what behavior you expect? What do you mean with "add strange character on message key"? Your given query should work, as described in the documentation: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/concepts/time-and-windows-in-ksqldb-queries/#windows-in-sql-queries https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/create-table-as-select/#synopsis